# how to get the data of selected node on TreeView kendo ui?

Tags: events, kendo-ui, treeview

By clicking the node of treeview I need to retrieve the data of treeview  which get loaded  by remote data .

```
var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: '<c:url value="/welcome/list/"/>',
                                dataType: "json"
                            }
                        },

                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                 hasChildren: "hasFiles",
                                children: "items"
                            }
                        }
                            });



               var tv= $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    dataSource: homogeneous,
                     dataTextField: "Name",
                           change:function(e){
                         // Need to retrive the "hasFiles" data on clicking the respective selected nodes of treeview 
} 
}
```

My JSON format of remote data will be like this.

[{"id":"1","Name":"five.txt","hasFiles":false,"items":[]},{"id":"2","Name":"one","hasFiles":true,"items":[{"id":"3","Name":"four","hasFiles":true,"items":[{"id":"4","Name":"four.txt","hasFiles":false,"items":[]}]}]}
];

I tried to accomplish using select and change event, its working only with local data  but not with remote data .
select event gives undefined whereas  change event is not even get called.Strangely change event works in jsbin but not in jsfiddle and my app. I dont find any error while running application.
Thanks in Advance.A sample Demo on fiddle will be a great help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your TreeView instantiation code will need a select event, and that select event will take the event as an argument. You will then use that event object to get the tree view data you need.

```
var tv= $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                 // other configuration code removed for brevity
                 select: function (e) { 
                     e.preventDefault();
                     var tree = $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView');
                     var dataItem = tree.dataItem(e.node);
                     // You will then have data item, and can use 
                     // the properties for whatever you need to do

                 }
}
```

Comment: how is it different than var item = this.dataItem(k.node);